# Prime factorization

Tags: factoring

What is the largest integer that can be factored by modern algorithm like **Msieve** and **GGNFS** in a time less than **5** hours with normal computers?

For example, can an integer like 
`6764305444023748746863375505235232356330698800019155741251564477831918942242883171154012150590008894127708940364431129`

be factored in less than 5 hours?

Comment: "... in a time less than **5** hours" on what? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer On regular computers, PC's ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is either a prime or a power of two, since those are really easy to factor. $\hspace{.5 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer Prime powers work too

Comment: The length of the *number* does not matter at all for factorization to be hard or lake a long time. If you have a large number with billions of bits, but contains only very small prime factors, then it is still simple to factor and can probably be done within seconds to minutes. Anyway, the much more impacting property is the length of the prime factors

Comment: Since factoring a 512 bit semiprime costs about $100, it's clearly more than a standard computer can do in a few hours. Your number has 392 bits, so factoring would be relatively cheap, but I don't know if it'd fall below your limit. If the number has small factors, ECM should be faster than GNFS.

Comment: @tylo GNFS depends on the size of the number. But some other algorithms like ECM depend on the size of the smallest factor. If your factors are small enough so that ECM is faster, then the cost will depend on the size of the factors. If all the factors are big enough so that GNFS is faster, the size of the factors doesn't matter.

Comment: Sounds like we have at least a few good answers here in the comments. Anyone care to write theirs up?

Comment: I can factor $2^n$ for arbitrary $n$. You might want to clarify the question to ask for the factorization of a random semiprime with $p$ and $q$ of a given size.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the largest integer that can be factored in 5 hours with a
>   normal computer?

That depends on a number of points.

**What do you consider a "normal" computer?**
 A 2015 Gamer-PC with a high-end quad (4) or octo (8) core CPU and more than one graphics card?
A 2010 Gamer-PC with a back-then modern CPU and a modern GPU?
A 2012 Multimedia-PC with a "weak" GPU and a moderate CPU (i5 class)?
A 2014 Workstation with two 18-core Intel Xeons and 4 deep-learning GPUs? 
 A standard office PC for the IT-department (featuring Gaming CPUs without dedicated GPUs)?
A standard office PC for non-IT people (having a starter-class CPU (=i3) and no dedicated GPU)?
A 2011 Ultrabook for 1k USD back then?
The term "normal" computer can't be quantified, however in the rest of the answer I'll explain how to calculate the upper limit on your PC, provided you measure one data-point.

**Now to the general methodology to get the desired bitlength on any PC you can run a test on.**
Find a program or library that offers the mentioned factoring algorithm and construct a composite number with the required properties. Note the bitlength of the main run-time affecting variable (length of composite number, length of smallest prime, etc.) and then measure the actual run-time (in seconds or whatever you like). Now if the algorithm has running time $\mathcal O(f(x))$, build the equation $\frac{f(x)}{f(x_{test})}=\frac{runtime}{runtime_{test}}$ and solve the equation $f(x)=f(x_{test})*\frac{runtime}{runtime_{test}}$ using your desired maximal run-time as $runtime$ (e.g. 5h).
If the run-time is given as $L_x[\alpha,c]:=\exp((c+o(1))(\ln\ln x)^{1-\alpha}(\ln x)^\alpha)$, then you need to calculate the $o(1)=\frac{\ln runtime}{(\ln\ln x)^{1-\alpha}(\ln x)^\alpha}-c$ and then you can solve the equation $L_x[\alpha,c]=runtime$ for either $runtime$ or $x$, depending on your needs.

Now a list of algorithms that need to be considered before asking for an upper limit. Each of them has their proper upper limit.

1. The most generic and best algorithm: The general number field sieve (GNFS), it's run-time only depends on the size of the modulus $n$ ($n$ is the actual modulus). The run-time is $L_n[1/3,(64/9)^{\frac{1}{3}}]$.
2. The next interesting algorithm is the special number field sieve (SNFS) with a running-time of $L_n[1/3,(32/9)^{\frac{1}{3}}]$. The drawback is that it only works against few composite numbers, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_number_field_sieve) for the details.
3. The elliptic curve factorization method (ECM) has a run-time of $L_p[1/2,\sqrt{2}]$ with $p$ being the smallest prime-factor of the number to be factored.
4. It is possible to check (and factor) for a number $n$ to be a perfect power using $\mathcal O((\ln n)^2)$ operations (= run-time).
5. Pollard-rho factoring can find a prime factor $p$ in $\mathcal O(\sqrt{p})$ time, so it's a good choice if moduli are made of several medium-sized primes (150-bits).
6. The Pollard p-1 factoring allows to factor a number $n=p*(n/p)$ in $\mathcal O(B*\ln n / \ln B)$ if the prime factorization of $p-1$ only contains primes smaller than $B$. Williams $p+1$ algorithm does the same for $p+1$.

Comment: @fgrieu, thank you, after your comment I noticed that $\mathcal O(\exp(c*...))\neq \exp((c+o(1))*(...))$. I'll fix the answer accordingly